# Is it safe and encouraged to use lazy var to replace implicitly unwrapped optionals in Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa

For example, consider the code following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    lazy var webView: WKWebView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        let _ = self.webView
        self.view = webView
    }
}
```

I think put `!` after each `self.webView` is really clumsy, so I came up with the above solution. Is it safe? If it is, are there any drawbacks for this pattern?

Comment: Why don't you unwrap it instead of putting ! after each use? You could also do var webView: WKWebView! if you know it won't be nil.

Comment: It won't be nil, and I can unwrap it every time. Then, don't you think something is going wrong? Writing codes that is meaningless and should therefore be avoided—I know it is just a bang, but meaningless code is still unnecessary. Besides, it actually lose some kind of compile time guarantee —otherwise API users will know for sure that they will be available *for sure*.

Comment: My point will hold only if this strategy doesn't have any drawbacks. This is why I asked this question.

Comment: The drawback is that I would consider this approach bad practice. If you make something a lazy var, there should be a purpose as to why you do it. In your example, you can instead define it as var webView: WKWebView! and do the init on the loadView() method. Consider if you say need to change the background color of webView. Where would you do it? In the lazy var or in the loadView()? Splitting it up in two places is bad for readability. If you instead put it in the lazy var, you end up with lots of additional code before you even get to the first function. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: https://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/11/20/swift-initialisation.html